# Customized admin drop down menu in Django python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am just a beginner in python. I have created two admin services called child and parent.

Parent - Table

id

name

type

Child - Table

pid

type

cname

In both services column "type" will be displayed in the drop down list.
When creating an entry for parent, if the "type" was not chosen in the parent service. 
That unchosen Parent id's should shown the in the child service in dropdown
Sorry for my bad english

```
# models.py

class Parent(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

    type = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='parent_set')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Child(models.Model):

    pid = models.IntegerField(max_length=30, blank=False)
    Type = models.ForeignKey(
         Parent,
         null=True, 
         on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         related_name='child_set' )
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for excluding some of the 'Parent' in drop down when creating a child ?

Comment: In the dropdown menu the unchosen type parent should get listed in the child service.

Comment: Meaning, while creating the parent. I won't choose the type in the dropdown menu. But, I need to list this parent as type in the child service dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haven't tested this. Please check if this works.

```
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
         chosen_types = Parent.objects.all().values_list('type', flat=True)
         context['adminform'].form.fields['Type'].queryset = Parent.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=chosen_types)
         return super(ChildAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, args, kwargs)
```

Comment: I have found my answer. I have used Parent.objects.filter. Thanks to you